# Check MySQL new record without Pooling

Tags: mysql, triggers, newrow

I am searching about a method to check for new records (in MySQL table) without pooling each **X seconds or minutes**.

I have found that **MySQL triggers** could be used but it can't call an external program or PHP file?

Comment: If there is no specific checking you can write an stored procedure, which be executed by trigger: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html

Comment: Thank you VANADIUM23, have you another method without using triggers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call external program in trigger through

```
sys_exec()
```

See:

http://crazytechthoughts.blogspot.jp/2011/12/call-external-program-from-mysql.html